# How can I use `case_when` to conditionally change a value based on string detection and current column values in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, case

I'm trying to conditionally change values in a column based on not detecting a string and the current values in the column.

```r
starwars %>%
  mutate(
    species = case_when(
      !str_detect(name, "Luke Skywalker") |
        !str_detect(name, "LUKE SKYWALKER") |
        !str_detect(name, "Darth Vader") |
        !str_detect(name, "DARTH VADER") &
        species == "Human"
      ~ "Other",
      .default = species
    )
  )
```

The result is that all values for species become "Other". I would have expected just the human characters (who are not Luke Skywalker or Darth Vader) to be "Other for species.

Comment: Try using "AND" - &, instead of "OR" - |.

Comment: This one?: `starwars %>%
  mutate(species = case_when(
    !str_detect(name, "Luke Skywalker|Darth Vader") ~ "Other",
    TRUE ~ species
  ))`

Comment: Hi, TarJae, I would also recommend using the new synthax for `case_when` with `....., .default = species)` instead of that old hacky `TRUE ~ species`. It works the same way, but is a bit clearer

Comment: since you're looking for whole strings, do you _need_ `str_detect`? I wonder if you can get by with `mutate(species = case_when(!tolower(name) %in% c("luke skywalker", "darth vader") & species == "Human" ~ "Other", .default=species))` or such (untested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have two conditions in your `mutate` command, you don't even need `case_when()` - you can just use `if_else()`.

Here's an easy way to combine your conditions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

starwars %>%
  mutate(species = if_else(!name %in% c("Luke Skywalker", "Darth Vader") &
                           species == "Human", "Other", species))
#> # A tibble: 87 × 14
#>    name     height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender
#>    <chr>     <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
#>  1 Luke Sk…    172    77 blond      fair       blue            19   male  mascu…
#>  2 C-3PO       167    75 <NA>       gold       yellow         112   none  mascu…
#>  3 R2-D2        96    32 <NA>       white, bl… red             33   none  mascu…
#>  4 Darth V…    202   136 none       white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu…
#>  5 Leia Or…    150    49 brown      light      brown           19   fema… femin…
#>  6 Owen La…    178   120 brown, gr… light      blue            52   male  mascu…
#>  7 Beru Wh…    165    75 brown      light      blue            47   fema… femin…
#>  8 R5-D4        97    32 <NA>       white, red red             NA   none  mascu…
#>  9 Biggs D…    183    84 black      light      brown           24   male  mascu…
#> 10 Obi-Wan…    182    77 auburn, w… fair       blue-gray       57   male  mascu…
#> # ℹ 77 more rows
#> # ℹ 5 more variables: homeworld <chr>, species <chr>, films <list>,
#> #   vehicles <list>, starships <list>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>